# Flash HTML5 canvas Clicktag

Tags: html, flash, canvas, jquery-animate, clicktag

Looking for definitive instructions for clicktag setup in Adobe Flash (now Animate) using the HTML5 canvas?

My guess is -

Create a button.
Give it a name.
Create an scene action.
And the code would be..?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener for "click" to the button.

```
button.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
function buttonClicked() {
    alert("Clicked!");
}
```

See more [here.](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/)

Answer (score 0):

In the head of your html doc

```
<script type="text/javascript">var clickTag = "https://www.google.com";</script>
```

right before the ending  > in your canvas div

```
onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)"
```

just having a button symbol in your canvas FLA gives you a cursor

Comment: Why does your clickTag point to google? Does that allow the clickTag to be set using DoubleClick studio? I'm confused about the appearance of what seem to be hardcoded URL's in all these answers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for these.  I've found an answer that works best for me within Animate CC (Flash) -

- Create a button, name it 'click' (for example)
- Add the following code to Actions:

  ```
  this.click.addEventListener('mousedown',bF);
  function bF(e){
  window.open(clickTag, "_blank");
  }
  ```

Note to make the HTML code validate for ads, you need to add the following line to the meta tags (size adjusted) -

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=160,height=600">
```

And there cannot be links to outside URLs.